# Ubuntu 14.04 Microphone Static

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, skype, microphone, 14.04

I haven't found any other askubuntu questions that I'm actually looking for.. So, every time I use my internal microphone, whether its during a Skype call or when I'm testing it on the gstreamer-properties program, there is horribly bad static.

I was attempting to Skype with my girlfriend earlier, but the static was louder then I was and she could barely make out what I was saying.

I have the latest version of Skype and everything is updated. I've attempted to change the microphone volume, didn't work. I tried changing from pulseaudio to an alternative, alsa and oss? I believe, didn't work. I have Windows 8.1 as my dualboot and the microphone works fine on there, so it is a Ubuntu 14.04 issue.

I'd like to have it fixed because Skyping is one of my top priorities and if I can't have a call without the static, I'm gonna be forced to go back to using Windows all-time. Please help guys, I like Ubuntu a lot and I'd just like to find a fix for this! :)

Comment: Do not uninstall pulse audio. Open Synaptic or first install synaptic and after that open it (**sudo apt-get install synaptic** or **sudo synaptic**) and search for a package called **gnome-alsa-mixer**. Also check for **pulseaudio-esound-compat**, **pavumeter** and **pavucontrol**. You should consider installing **sox**. After you're done you can adjust sound levels and uncheck **Mic Boost** using Gnome Alsa Mixer present in your Multimedia section. If it works, you can use pulse audio volume control in the future, and go back to gnome alsa mixer when you experience same issues.

Comment: and install `libasound2-plugins`

Comment: None of these worked :(

Answer (score 2):

I have the same environment (Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04).
The tip given in the following link worked perfectly for me. 
http://itsfoss.com/how-to-solve-microphone-not-working-in-skype-quick-tip/

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please consider editing your question to add a general description of what's involved in that article. Then you can use the link for reference purposes. This way if the link becomes unavailable for some reason, your answer will still be helpful.